# How to prevent sql injection in stored procedure with dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008

The reason I have dynamic SQL in my stored procedure is because I need to pass in the database name on which to execute the stored procedure on. Due legacy db design the stored procedure talks to another as well as the database the stored procedure is on.

1. will `sp_executesql` protect me from SQL injection?
2. our owasp manager wants me to sanitise the parameters at the stored procedure level how the heck am I going to do that? I already use parametrised query to call the stored procedure from C#

Code:

```
SELECT     
    data.userid, 
    aspnet_users.username, 
    CASE 
       WHEN data.email LIKE '%@b.c' THEN '' 
       ELSE data.email 
    END AS email, 
    data.islockedout, 
    data.isapproved 
FROM
    dbo.aspnet_membership data 
INNER JOIN 
    aspnetdb.dbo.aspnet_users ON aspnet_users.userid = data.userid 
LEFT JOIN  
    martin.dbo.application_users ON application_users.username = aspnet_users.username COLLATE latin1_general_ci_as 
LEFT JOIN  
    martin.dbo.life_company_users ON life_company_users.user_id = application_users.id 
WHERE      
    ((aspnet_users.username LIKE '%ss%' OR ISNULL(@username, '') = '') 
     AND (data.email LIKE '%ya.com%' OR ISNULL(@email, '') = '') 
     AND (@lifeCompany = life_company_users.life_company_id OR @lifeCompany = 0)
```

Comment: Why don't you provide one sp for every database? Then the query dont need to use dynamic sql

Comment: because they are left joined. IT's all in one sproc

Comment: Best thing to do is check the name passed in and if it is not part of a valid list of databases, throw an error. In other words check it against a limited list